# Get jQuery two-handle slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-slider

I have the following HTML and JS structure for using the jQuery two-handle range slider:

**.html**

```
<p>
  <input class="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:black; background: transparent; text-align: center;" type="text">
</p>
<div class="slider-range"></div>
```

**.js**

```
$(function() {
  $(".slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [0, 1000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $(".amount").val("$" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

I think I need to add a `value="..."` to my `<input>` element, but how do I capture the value range from the two sliders according to my JavaScript code? Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r6oekgd6/

Comment: I need to collect the value from the slider in the `input` element, so I can send that to the server.

Comment: Why not store them in hidden inputs when you slide the slider?

Comment: How do I go about extracting them from the JS function and storing them in a hidden input field?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sh0q62b7/

Answer (score 0):

The values can be extracted as:

```
var minimum_val = $(".slider-range").slider("values",0)
var maximum_val = $(".slider-range").slider("values",1)
```